# Custom Event Using Parsley Submit

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager, parsley.js

I'm trying to add a custom event to a form for Google Analytics tracking. The form is using Parsley to validate. I'm confused on where to add the snippet:

```
dataLayer.push({'event' : 'signUpForm'});
```

into the javascript:

```
    initParsley: function()
{
    $body.find('form.js-validate').parsley();
},
```

Does anyone know a good way to handle this, or do I need to provide more information?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [Parsley Events Demo](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/events.html?firstname=&lastname=asdf&fullname=8)

I haven't worked with parsley before, but it looks like you can do something like this:

```
initParsley: function () {
    $body.find('form.js-validate')
         .parsley()
         .subscribe('parsley:form:validate', function (formInstance) {
            if (formInstance.isValid()) {
                dataLayer.push({
                    'event': 'signUpForm'
                });
                return;
            }
        });
},
```

So when the form is submitted, you're subscribing to the `parsley:form:validate` event, and passing-in the `formInstance` to actual check to see if the form is valid. If the form is valid, then you're pushing your `dataLayer` event to GTM, and then submitting the form. Nice thing about this is that it will only send the event if the form is valid - which I believe is what you're after.